# SEO: How does a crawler consider PHP built pages?

Tags: php, seo, web-crawler

Two HTML web pages generated using PHP.
One script that creates a footer which is referenced by both web pages.

Does a crawler consider the footer HTML content once or twice?

Comment: Sounds like a quiz. The A-train is coming at 70mph... while the E-train is coming South at 90, who meets who first?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Didn't realise SEO questions were inappropriate sorry. It is about how to design a web page using PHP, with SEO in mind so perhaps not completely off topic?

Comment: off topic php has NOTHING to do with it, no more than your webserver sodtware or OS

Comment: Im a little confused now. Please could someone explain the down votes?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" i voted of the third clause principle

Comment: Dagon, thanks for the explanation. Fred, if my reputation is going downtown on that E train at 90, and I've apologized for my lack of research, how many more down-votes before it stops?

Comment: dont take it personally, i'm just not a very nice person.

Comment: Not at all, thanks for taking a look at the question. If you didn't keep me in line, id probably get rather lazy with all the knowledgable people ready to help on here. Good evening all.

Comment: @Pete I didn't downvote you. Voted to close yes, but not downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crawlers don'see or care about server-side code. They only see the content output by a requested URL just like any user-agent.